# How to use Linear Indicator dynamic stock values

Tags: flutter, progress-bar, linear-regression, progress-indicator, linearprogressindicator

I want linear indicator for dynamic values how to use condition in stock details and color values

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
double stockValue = 0.5; // update stock value 
LinearProgressIndicator(
   backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFB4B4B4),
   valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(stockValue == 1?Colors.red:Colors.green),
   value: stockValue,
),
```